# Нужно ли брать в кавычки имена героев из сериалов, кино, мультфильмов и т. д.?

Tags: ономастика, кавычки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли брать в кавычки имена персонажей, если в предложении нет указания на сериалы, кино, мультфильмы и т. д.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кавычки не нужны, иначе эти имена будут выглядеть как названия чего-либо.

**Примеры** из Нацкорпуса русского языка:

*Место прежних героев и бледных от нежности женщин заняли **Чичиков** и **Хлестаков.*** [К. Г. Паустовский. Орест Кипренский (1936)]

*В пролете лестницы художник увидел окно, разбитое, и через него двор, тот самый, что мог видеть и **Раскольников.*** [С. А. Дангулов. Горяев (1981)]

*Тогда Варя приезжала как **Анна Каренина** ― мирить брата с женой.* [И. Грекова. Фазан (1984)]

*Будто бы **Мальвина** решила поменяться со старухой **Шапокляк** ролями.* [Ирина Краева. Тим и Дан, или Тайна «Разбитой коленки»: сказочная повесть (2007)]

*Как сказал бы небезызвестный вам **Капитан Джек Воробей:** «Нужен подходящий момент»…* [Татьяна Соломатина. Отойти в сторону и посмотреть (2011)]

Answer (score 3):

Имена кавычками не обрамляются, даже если в предложении нет названий сериалов, или мультфильмов, или сказок. Достаточно такое собственное имя написать с прописной буквы.

> С прописной буквы пишутся нарицательные слова, выступающие как названия персонажей в сказках, пьесах, баснях и некоторых других произведениях художественной литературы, фольклора, напр.: *Красная Шапочка, Змей Горыныч, Серый Волк, Синяя Борода, Дед Мороз, Петушок со Шпорами* (герои сказок); *Кот, Пёс, Сахар, Хлеб* (персонажи «Синей птицы» М. Метерлинка); *Весна, Леший* (персонажи «Снегурочки» А. Островского), *Городничий, Душечка, Левша, Некто в сером* (литературные персонажи)...

*Карнавал уже начался. Каких только костюмов не было! И **Буратино** с длинным носом, и три мушкетера, и **Золушка**, и **Карабас Барабас**, и казак в бурке* ([В. В. Голявкин. Мой добрый папа).

Потом он зашёл в театральный магазин на Рылеева. Купил довольно уродливую маску **Буратино**. В этой маске я просидел целый час за стойкой бара "Юность". [Сергей Довлатов. Чемодан (1986)]

Если же имеется в виду название (например, книги), то кавычки нужны.
Отнеси их в макулатуру и поменяй на **"Буратино"**... [Сергей Довлатов. Наши (1983)]

[Собственные имена людей, животных, мифологических существ и производные от них слова](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=83#pp83)